# Visual Studios 2015 Gridview Conditional Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gridview

I'm fairly new to C#, so i'm not really good at coding.  Currently, i'm using Visual Studios Community 2015 and been mostly working in design view.

I've created a gridview that is bound to a SQL data source that allows a user to update a record.

Now the thing that I want to do is:

I have 2 columns.  Server and status.  I want to highlight the status column based on a given text.

Ex: Status=done, should be highlighted in green.

What is the best method to achieve this?  Can someone point me in the right direction, whether linking a guide or helping with the code behind.

Thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="SID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SID" HeaderText="SID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Servers" HeaderText="Servers" SortExpression="Servers" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:it_ConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Main_Status_test]" UpdateCommand="Update [Main_Status_test] Set [Status]=@Status Where [SID]=@SID"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    {
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[3].Text == "done")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else if (row.Cells[3].Text == "not done")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the markup code for gridview?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea.  I will update this shortly.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to check what the status is and change the color accordingly?

Comment: Yea, that is pretty much it.  If status is "done", it should highlight the record green, and if its "not done" it should highlight the record in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the below coding to the GridView1 DataBound event.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[2].Text == "done")
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else if (row.Cells[2].Text == "WHATEVER YOU WANT")
            {
             row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.'Whatevercoloryouwant'
            }
            //etc...
        }
```

Comment: Awesome, this works.  There were some minor typos in the code you provided.  How would you do this for the status column only?  I'm researching this now.  Thanks alot for this!

Comment: Glad it worked. The row.Cells[2] specifies the third column in that row (uses the index [2]). If you want a different column to be selected, just change the '2' to whatever column index you want to check. Don't forget to mark as answer :)